# AngularJS - Factory, http request and callbacks

Tags: angularjs, callback

I'm learning AngularJS from this tutorial http://curran.github.io/screencasts/introToAngular/exampleViewer/#/42

*There's also a video on youtube, which walks you trough the whole process*

When you open the link (example 42), you'll see where I got stuck.

I'd like you to give me an easy explanation on what's going on on these lines

```
countryApp.factory('countries', function($http){

    var cachedData;

    function getData(callback){ // *1
      if(cachedData) {
        callback(cachedData); // *1
      } else {
        $http.get('countries.json').success(function(data){
          cachedData = data;
          callback(data); // *1
        });
      }
    }

    return {
      list: getData, // *2
      find: function(name, callback){ // *3
        getData(function(data) {
          var country = data.filter(function(entry){
            return entry.name === name;
          })[0];
          callback(country); // *1
        });
      }
    };
  });

  countryApp.controller('CountryListCtrl', function ($scope, countries){
    countries.list(function(countries) { // *2
      $scope.countries = countries;
    });
  });

  countryApp.controller('CountryDetailCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, countries){
    countries.find($routeParams.countryName, function(country) { // *3
      $scope.country = country;
    });
  });
```

*1 - What is the "callback" function and what does it exactly do? Is it some built in function ? If not why there is no definition of the function.

*2 - In the youtube video, the guy said that "list" is a function, why is it declared with ":" ? Is the "list" in CountryListCtrl (controller) same function as the one in the `return{}` in countries (factory)

*3 - same as "*2" with different function -> **find**

Comment: You, and the author of the tutorial, should learn about promises. Here's a blog post that should explain why the above code is an anti-pattern. http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/

Answer (score 2):

**1)** [Callbacks](http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/) in [Javascript](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/) is one of the concepts that tires to capture asyncronous nature of of processes initiated in the code. Basically it is any function what is called after some process has changed its state - e.g. finished.
In more general way it has to deal with [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

More examples of callbacks, to grasp the idea:

- [in jQuery.animation, when animation on the page is over, callback fires](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)
- [in Angular $http method, when data is received from the server (or failed to receive), success of error callbacks are fired](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

**2) and 3)** - this is the way define set of methods which is provided by factory:

When in controller you call `countries.list` it calls `getData` function which is defined earlier in factory. In short that a way to define methods available **only inside of a factory** - in this case it's `getData`, and the **ones that are available outside** - `list` and `find`, when it's used in controller.
So in `return` statement you have javascript object in which you can get `value` by calling object with `key`:

```
var myFactory = {
    "list" : "getData",
    "find" : 42
};
myFactory.list
//Outputs: "getData";
myFactory.find
//Outputs:42;
```

Answer (score 2):

### 1.

`callback` is just the single argument name of the `getData` function. Within the function body it is used like a function - it is a [callback function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29).

When `getData` is called, it is supplied with a callback function:

```
getData(function(data) {
  // ...
});
```

This is done within another function (assigned to the `find` property of the returned object) which also has an argument called `callback`. Be careful though, these are different variables which just happen to have the same name. They exist within completely separate scopes. The callback passed to `find` is used within the callback passed to `getData`:

```
find: function(name, callback){
  getData(function(data) {          // define getData callback
    // ...
    callback(country);              // call find callback
  });
}
```

### 2.

`list` is the name of a property of the object returned by the `countries` factory. It's value is the `getData` *function*:

```
return {
  list: getData,
  // ...
}
```

**This object is what is injected into your controller as `countries`**, so when you call `countries.list(...)` in your controller you are calling the function which was assigned to the list property in the factory (i.e. `getData`).

### 3.

See #2. In the controller, `countries.find(...)` calls the function assigned to the `find` property of the object returned in the factory.